# Regarding Datepicker for weekend

Tags: java, android

I have button where I display the date. In this if I select the date which falls under weekend then I want that it should immediately prompt with message. 
I run the code it check only myDay==2. Not the myDay ==1 if I select Saturday. When I select weekend I should display current date instead of selected weekend date.

```
private void setupDate(int day, int month, int year) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(day, month, year);
        int myDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (myDay == 1 || myDay == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(DateTimePickerActivity.this, "My good day is  " + myDay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String strMonth = ((month + 1) <= 9) ? ("0" + (month + 1)) : String.valueOf(month + 1);
            views.button_date.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + strMonth + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        }


    }

    private void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog
                (
                        this,
                         dpListenerView,
                       /* new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            } },*/
                        //this,
                        x_year,
                        month,
                        day
                );
        datepickerdialog.show();
    }

   class ButtonViews {
        Button button_time;
        Button button_date;

        public ButtonViews() {
            button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
            button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
        }
    }

  class dpListener implements OnDateSetListener {
      @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

              setupDate(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);

      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`

1. Sunday = 1
2. Monday = 2
3. Tuesday = 3
4. Wednesday = 4
5. Thursday = 5
6. Friday = 6
7. Saturday = 7

   use,

   if (myDay == 1 || myDay == 7) {}